# WP: How to display a jQuery slider instead of a normal post with next/prev button

Tags: php, jquery

Here is the problem, I have a WP site that changes the display depending on the presence or not of a parameter in the URL.
If no parameter the whole post shows normally.

If the user has the parameter in the URL the post will be split into many sections (break lines are used as separators) and each time he clicks next the page will load and the URL will change to "/2" for the second element of the post for example. This is what I have for the moment and it works.

With parameter in the URL I want the users to have a slide that only loads the content without the page loading but I can't find a way to do this in WP.

Is it possible with jQuery? For example, load all the content first and show the appropriate section after each click? How would you go about it?

I'm not asking for a code but the logic that you'll use to tackle this issue if you were in my shoes.

Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: its too broad, it might be better to use a slider that already have this functionality out of the box

Comment: I would have liked to use something that already exists, but I can't find anything that handles this kind of situations.

Comment: can't find? its time to step up for _google fu_ =) here's one, you can control how many sliders you want relative to viewport, prev/next, dotted, left right arrows, you name it: https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Is this related to Wp and how it handles single,php? All I can see is different ways to create a slide and it's not what I'm looking for. I want to have a slider but in WP and in certain conditions. Thank you though.

Comment: its not port into WP kind of solution, you could hire an experienced developer to add it an apply to your website though, you would need to add the library and apply it in your markup that does the rendering of single post loop

Comment: I already have a dev working on this and I'm trying to find solutions for him. I hope that will ring a bell. Thanks again.

Comment: Here is what I got from him and I hope you can help with this issue as you are the only one engaged :) 
"The problem with that is we are using single post sections as slide and issue is that single post sections cant be treated as a item in slider because we are getting single slides from the post content that is as a whole"

Comment: just add a custom query, surely wordpress already have this in api, so basically each post, loop it and by that, construct the markup that fits using the slick slider. fairly straightforward